# Show loader image until the background image is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to implement a loader for a background image until the whole image is completely loaded using jquery. I have tried the various method to do this. Since the image is specified in the CSS I could not specify the exact image id or class. Finally I end up doing this ,

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

But doing this it is happening when the window is loaded. I wanted to happen it until the image is completely loaded. 
And the background image comes under the following section

```
<div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="test_banner services_banner">
</div>
```

It would be great if somebody give a helping hand to manage this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using any of the `lazyload` plugins. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Please post a full example (e.g. a jsfiddle) with the markup and the css. Can't really imagine what it's looking like and what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Grab the background image from CSS, create a new image with the same filename, and when that is loaded, remove the loader etc.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you could use a multiple background-image

example:

```css
div {
  height:90vh;
    width:90vw;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/nature/) center,
    url(http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Customizable-jQuery-Loader-Plugin-Center-Loader/img/loader1.gif) center center no-repeat ;/* this works once/untill image has been loaded */
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The Gif background remains here but is painted behi,d the big image. It is seen as long as the big image is not loaded ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your suggestion. But while following this it is showing the image loading step by step. What I wanted is show the main image only after complete load. Just like replace the loader with the image.

Comment: @MuneerMuhammed, looks like an old question, but progressive (interlaced)  jpg avoid this, it loads image faster, then resolution is increased untill fully loaded to avoid showing it bits by bits. photoshop,gimp alike many other programs have this option . there's evn online tools : https://coding.tools/progressive-jpeg , https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/make-jpeg-progressive-without-compression.php , ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Create a "Please Wait, Loading..." Animation</title>
<style>
    .overlay{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) url("http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Customizable-jQuery-Loader-Plugin-Center-Loader/img/loader1.gif") center no-repeat;
    }
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
    /* Turn off scrollbar when body element has the loading class */
    body.loading{
        overflow: hidden;   
    }
    /* Make spinner image visible when body element has the loading class */
    body.loading .overlay{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Initiate an Ajax request on button click
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    // Adding timestamp to set cache false
    $.get("/examples/php/customers.php?v="+ $.now(), function(data){
        //$("body").html(data);
    });       
});

// Add remove loading class on body element depending on Ajax request status
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function(){
        $("body").addClass("loading"); 
    },
    ajaxStop: function(){ 
        $("body").removeClass("loading"); 
    }    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button">Get Customers Details</button>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```